# Reading a .txt file with escaped characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, special-characters

I'm having difficulty reading a file with escaped characters in Ruby...

My text file has the string "First Line\r\nSecond Line" and when I use File.read, I get a string back that escapes my escaped characters: "First Line\r\nSecond Line"

These two strings are not the same things...

```
1.9.2-p318 :006 > f = File.read("file.txt")
 => "First Line\\r\\nSecond Line" 
1.9.2-p318 :007 > f.count('\\')
 => 2

1.9.2-p318 :008 > f = "First Line\r\nSecond Line"
 => "First Line\r\nSecond Line" 
1.9.2-p318 :009 > f.count('\\')
 => 0
```

How can I get the File.read to not escape my escaped characters?

Comment: Are you saying the file contains the literal characters \ followed by r followed by \ followed by n but you want these to be converted to carriage return and linefeed in the Ruby string?

Comment: Based on your irb output your file contains the character \ followed by the carriage return character. How did you end up with a messy file like that? It doesn't make sense to have such a text file.

Comment: @Casper A mysql dump is an easy way to end up with a "messy" file like that

Answer (score 1):

Create a method to remove all the additional escape characters that the File.Read method added, like this:

```
    # Define a method to handle unescaping the escape characters
    def unescape_escapes(s)
      s = s.gsub("\\\\", "\\") #Backslash
      s = s.gsub('\\"', '"')  #Double quotes
      s = s.gsub("\\'", "\'")  #Single quotes
      s = s.gsub("\\a", "\a")  #Bell/alert
      s = s.gsub("\\b", "\b")  #Backspace
      s = s.gsub("\\r", "\r")  #Carriage Return
      s = s.gsub("\\n", "\n")  #New Line
      s = s.gsub("\\s", "\s")  #Space
      s = s.gsub("\\t", "\t")  #Tab
      s
    end
```

Then see it in action:

```
    # Create your sample file
    f = File.new("file.txt", "w")
    f.write("First Line\\r\\nSecond Line")
    f.close

    # Use the method to solve your problem
    f = File.read("file.txt")
    puts "BEFORE:", f
    puts f.count('\\')
    f = unescape_escapes(f)
    puts "AFTER:", f
    puts f.count('\\')


    # Here's a more elaborate use of it
    f = File.new("file2.txt", "w")
    f.write("He used \\\"Double Quotes\\\".")
    f.write("\\nThen a Backslash: \\\\")
    f.write('\\nFollowed by \\\'Single Quotes\\\'.')
    f.write("\\nHere's a bell/alert: \\a")
    f.write("\\nThis is a backspaces\\b.")
    f.write("\\nNow we see a\\rcarriage return.")
    f.write("\\nWe've seen many\\nnew lines already.")
    f.write("\\nHow\\sabout\\ssome\\sspaces?")
    f.write("\\nWe'll also see some more:\\n\\ttab\\n\\tcharacters")
    f.close

    # Read the file without the method
    puts "", "BEFORE:"
    puts File.read("file2.txt")

    # Read the file with the method
    puts "", "AFTER:"
    puts unescape_escapes(File.read("file2.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just hack them back in.

```
foo = f.gsub("\r\n", "\\r\\n")
#=> "First Line\\r\\nSecond Line"

foo.count("\\")
#=> 2
```